# Настройка dockerfile для airflow и зпуска на сервере

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile, pipelines

У меня стоит задача написать dockerfile для запуска pipelin'а. Т.е. я должен установить apache airflow и все написанные скрипты засунуть в airflow/dags и запустить. Я впервые пишу dockerfile и не очень-то понимаю, правильно ли все. Я взял Dockerfile с https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow и пытаюсь переделать под свои задачи. Получается так:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch
LABEL maintainer="Gene_project"

# Never prompts the user for choices on installation/configuration of packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

# Airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.5
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_DEPS=""
ARG PYTHON_DEPS=""
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

# Define en_US.
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8

RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        freetds-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
    ' \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps \
        freetds-bin \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils \
        curl \
        rsync \
        netcat \
        locales \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && pip install 'redis==3.2' \
    && if [ -n "${PYTHON_DEPS}" ]; then pip install ${PYTHON_DEPS}; fi \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

COPY . ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/dags/pipeline
RUN pip install -r ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/dags/pipeline/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080 5555 8793

USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

RUN airflow initdb

CMD ["webserver", "scheduler", "worker"]
```

Вылезает ошибка: **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"webserver\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**
Вопрос в том, нормальный ли докерфайл?

Comment: В примере что по ссылке, то что содержит `CMD` является "аргументами" для скрипта указанного в `ENTRYPOINT` - "/entrypoint.sh" (и кстати, там об этом же и написано каментом) , а у Вас его нет. Отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: @nobody Я изменил немного файл, сделал **ENTRYPOINT ["airflow"]**, а **CMD ["webserver"]** . airflow запустился, но мне надо еще запустить *airflow scheduler* и *airflow worker*. Как это сделать? Я пытался в CMD передать, но так не работает

Comment: Смотреть пример с которого Вы это всё скопировали, а именно скрипт `entrypoint.sh` именно там, если не ошибаюсь, это всё и запускается. В любом случае, Вам придётся сделать что-то похожее.

Comment: @nobody В докерфайле зпускается скрипт entrypoint и уже в нем все запускается, неужели нельзя запустить все без доп файла (все через докере)

Comment: Разумеется можно, запускайте.

Comment: @nobody как? Я пытался CMD передать несколько параметров, но так не работает..

Comment: Так же, как и `initdb` запустили, вестимо.